# Is it normal sqlite.fetchall() is slow?

Tags: performance, sqlite, fetchall

I have an SQL query that selects from two inner joined tables. The select statement takes about 50 seconds. However, the `fetchall()` takes 788 seconds for only 981 results:

```
time0 = time.time()
self.cursor.execute("SELECT spectrum_id, feature_table_id "+
                    "FROM spectrum AS s "+
                    "INNER JOIN feature AS f "+
                    "ON f.msrun_msrun_id = s.msrun_msrun_id "+
                    "INNER JOIN (SELECT feature_feature_table_id, min(rt) AS rtMin, max(rt) AS rtMax, min(mz) AS mzMin, max(mz) as mzMax "+
                                 "FROM convexhull GROUP BY feature_feature_table_id) AS t "+
                    "ON t.feature_feature_table_id = f.feature_table_id "+
                    "WHERE s.msrun_msrun_id = ? "+
                    "AND s.scan_start_time >= t.rtMin "+
                    "AND s.scan_start_time <= t.rtMax "+
                    "AND base_peak_mz >= t.mzMin "+
                    "AND base_peak_mz <= t.mzMax", spectrumFeature_InputValues)
print 'query took:',time.time()-time0,'seconds'
    
time0 = time.time()
spectrumAndFeature_ids = self.cursor.fetchall()      
print time.time()-time0,'seconds since to fetchall'
```

Is there a reason why `fetchall()` takes so long? Doing:

```
while 1:
    info = self.cursor.fetchone()
    if info:
        <do something>
    else:
        break
```

is just as slow as :

```
allInfo = self.cursor.fetchall()         
for info in allInfo:
    <do something>
```

Comment: I would try to move as many of the strict equality constraints as possible into the `INNER JOIN`'s `ON` clause, because that would (hopefully) minimize the size of the heap hitting the `WHERE` section (inequalities usually get loaded to memory for a full heap scan, at which point your timescale is determined by heap size, not index -- this is annoying and perhaps unintuitive, but mostly unavoidable due to the non-deterministic nature of inequality query result size).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `fetchall()` is as slow as looping over `fetchone()` due to the `arraysize` of the `Cursor` object being set to 1.

To speed things up you can loop over `fetchmany()`, but to see a performance gain, you need to provide it with a size parameter bigger than 1, otherwise it'll fetch "many" by batches of `arraysize`, i.e. 1.

It is quite possible that you can get the performance gain simply by raising the value of `arraysize`, but I have no experience doing this, so you may want to experiment with that first by doing something like:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
>>> cu = conn.cursor()
>>> cu.arraysize
1
>>> cu.arraysize = 10
>>> cu.arraysize
10
```

More on the above here: http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchmany

Comment: I accepted this because it answer my question, but I can't get it to speed up using fetchmany. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running a complex query, try to create a table using that complex query and then run a select on the created table so the performance is good.